# Poverty estimates from Census API

Tags: usa, api, census, economy

I am trying to complete a project for a local nonprofit I work with. I am trying to use the Census API to pull in certain estimates in each of the counties they work in.

I am trying to pull in poverty estimates at the tract, sub-county, and county levels. The data I need is in the S1701 dataset under the American Community Survey. It seems that I can't find the variables I need to call the data through the API.

For example, I need the estimate for "Population for whom poverty status is determined". I can't find the variable I need in any of the tables listed [here](https://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/acs-1year.html).

I am new to all of this. If anyone has any advice, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check the subject table section from the page you linked to.

https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs1/subject/variables.html
It includes variables from the S1701 table.

Answer (score 1):

For the county level, [maps and tables](https://www.census.gov/data-tools/demo/saipe/saipe.html) of the 2016 poverty levels has already been created.